# How do i expire cookies after an hour in asp

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

I want my cookies expire after an hour. I'm doing it in classic asp and I am a newbie.

I have tried this;

```
Response.Cookies("NumVisits").Expires=dateadd("h", 1, now())
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

it works fine for me

```
Response.Cookies("NumVisits").expires = dateadd("n",+60,now())
```

Comment: still never work for me.

Here is my full code
<%
dim numvisits
Response.Cookies("NumVisits").expires = dateadd("n",+60,now())
numvisits=request.cookies("NumVisits")
%>
<body>
<%
if numvisits="" then
   response.cookies("NumVisits")=1
else
   %>
   <script>
$(function() {
  $('button,input[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);
}); 
</script>
   <%
end if
%>
<button>hello</button>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```vb
<% 
dim numvisits 
numvisits = 40 'Get the number of visits
Response.Cookies("NumVisits") = numvisits
Response.Cookies("NumVisits").expires = dateadd("n",+60,now())
%> 
<body>
<% if numvisits= "" then 
   Response.Cookies("NumVisits")=1 
   else %>
<script> 
$(function() { 
    $('button,input[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true); 
});  
</script>
<% end if %> 
<button>hello</button> 
</body>
```